# Survey Shiny App : A progress bar which progresses with the succession of pages (multiples pages, progress bar and Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar, shinyjs

Good Morning, Good Evening,
I hope you are well,

I try to program whith Shiny a survey app with multiples pages. I use Shiny shinyWidgets to schedule my questions and shinyjs to organize the display, question by question. The code is below. All is ok.

I would program a progress bar : so the respondent can know where he is in the questionnaire. That's the great idea no ? Well, but when I tried to program my idea that difficulties started.

I don't know how to operate my progress bar with my buttons. I have buttons from 0 to ... (in my exemple 2). I don't know how to tell my progress bar how to move forward according to the button.

**EDIT:** For example, if a have 10 pages (and so 10 buttons "next"), when a click on the first next button (button 1 --> moves on the second pages), my progress bar moves to 10%. And when a click on the second button (button 2 -->
moves on the third page), my progress bar moves to 20%, .... So, when a click to the last button (Button 10 --> last question), my progress bar moves to 100%.

In my example below, I have 2 questions. So, when I click on button 1, the progress bar would be in 50%. And when I click on button 2, the progress bar would be in 100%

Thank you in advance,
Aurélien.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    style = "width:800px",
    titlePanel(
      fluidRow(column(width=2, img(src="myImage.png")), 
               column(width=10, progressBar(id = "progress", value = 0, total = 100, display_pct = TRUE)))),
               
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(), 
    
    panel(
      
    div(id = "Intro", 
    h4("Bienvenue sur notre questionnaire en ligne. Nous vous remercions d’accepter de répondre à cette étude en ligne menée 
      par l’Institut d’études et de sondages Su-R-vey. Cette étude sera traitée de façon anonyme. Nous vous garantissons la 
      confidentialité de cette interview. Ce questionnaire vous prendra une vingtaine de minutes."), 
    
    actionButton("button0", "Suivant")),
    
    # Question S1. 
    hidden(div(id = "S1",
               
    radioGroupButtons("S1", label = p("Vous êtes :"),
                                 choices = list("Un Homme" = 1, "Une femme" = 2), selected = "", direction = "vertical"),
               
    actionButton("button1", "Suivant"))), 
    
    # Question S2. 
    hidden(div(id = "S2",
               
               numericInput("S2", label = p("Quel âge avez-vous ?"), value = ""),    
               
               actionButton("button2", "Suivant"))), 
    
    # Fin du questionnaire
    hidden(div(id = "fin", 
               
               p("Ce questionnaire est à présent terminé. Je vous remercie vivement pour votre participation et je vous souhaite une bonne fin de journée / soirée"),
               
               actionButton("submit", "Submit"))) 
    
    )),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$button0, {
      shinyjs::hide(id = "Intro")
      shinyjs::show(id = "S1")
    })
    
      observeEvent(input$button1, {
      shinyjs::hide(id = "S1")
      shinyjs::show(id = "S2")
    })
      
      observeEvent(input$button2, {
        shinyjs::hide(id = "S2")
        shinyjs::show(id = "fin")
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$button0, {
        for (i in 1:100) {
          updateProgressBar(
            session = session,
            id = "progress",
            value = i, total = 100,
            title = paste("Process", trunc(i/10))
          )
        }
      })
    
})
```

Comment: Does [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/progress-bar-example.html) help?

Comment: I don't want an "automatic" progress bar. I don't know if my post was clear, so I have add some details. I have "next" buttons to go from one page to another. And when I go to the next page, the progress bar would increase by 10% (if I have 10 pages --> rules : incresing of 1/sum(i) with i a page of this app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripping out everything not related to maintenance of the progress bar, here's an MWE:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui = fluidPage(
    style = "width:800px",
    panel(progressBar(id = "progress", value=0, total=100, display_pct = TRUE)),
    panel(uiOutput("pageContent")),
    actionButton("button", "Suivant")
  )
  
server = function(input, output, session) {
  v <- reactiveValues(
    currentPage=1,
    nPages=10 # nPages doesn't need to be reactive for this MWE, but might need to be in reality
  )
  observe({
    updateProgressBar(session, "progress", value=v$currentPage, total=v$nPages)
  })
  output$pageContent <- renderUI({
    paste0("Content for page ", v$currentPage)
  })
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    v$currentPage <- v$currentPage + 1
    if (v$currentPage == (v$nPages+1)) {
      # Finish processing here
    } else { 
      updateProgressBar(session, "progress", value=v$currentPage*v$nPages, total=100) # Total required to force indicator updatde
      updateActionButton(session, "button", label=ifelse(v$currentPage == v$nPages, "Fin", "Suivant"))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Your major work will be in updating `output$pageContent`.  I would consider making each page a separate module.  Even though that's not strictly necessary (as there will only ever be one instance of each page), I think it's still worthwhile as it protects you against accidental duplication of `input` and `output` ids and keeps a clear separation between "display of questionnnire" and "management of questionnaire progress".